# Dockerfile - Does USER directive make shell switch to its home directory?

Tags: linux, bash, docker, busybox

As root, We are launching docker container with ansible:

```
FROM python:3.7-alpine3.9

ENV HOME /home/someteam

RUN apk add --no-cache --virtual .build-deps python3-dev gcc linux-headers musl-dev


RUN addgroup someteam --gid=5566; \

    adduser -G someteam -Du 5566 -d /home/someteam -m -s /bin/bash someteam; \

    chown -R someteam $HOME

USER someteam

ADD script.sh /home/someteam/script.sh

ENTRYPOINT ["/home/envteam/script.sh"]
```

---

Below is the error with local test:

```
adduser: unrecognized option: d
BusyBox v1.29.3 (2019-01-24 07:45:07 UTC) multi-call binary.

Usage: adduser [OPTIONS] USER [GROUP]

Create new user, or add USER to GROUP

        -h DIR          Home directory
        -g GECOS        GECOS field
        -s SHELL        Login shell
        -G GRP          Group
        -S              Create a system user
        -D              Don't assign a password
        -H              Don't create home directory
        -u UID          User id
        -k SKEL         Skeleton directory (/etc/skel)
chown: unknown user someteam
```

---

Before running second `RUN` directive, `whoami` is `root`

Problem is, shell commands running in `script.sh` are not use relative paths when the docker container is launched using ansible

```
- name: Run docker container from ansible
  command: docker container run --rm -e SOMETHING={{somthing}}  111112223333.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/someteamteam/deploy:v1
```

---

1)

Expecting `ADD` directive to run in `/home/someteam`, 
Does `USER someteam` switch shell to `/home/someteam`? or Do we still need `WORKDIR $HOME`? Any redundant options used with `adduser`...

2)

Do we need `chown` command?